# How to echo an error class to label and form elements that have errors?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, multidimensional-array, error-handling

I am using a PHP validation library. It only comes with an example of how to show a list of errors at the top of the form.

How can I make this so it will echo ' class="error"' in the label and form element for each field that is currently in error?

**Form HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><label for="first_name">First Name</label></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><label for="last_name">Last name</label></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><label for="phone">Phone</label></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><label for="email">Email</label></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><label for="state">State</label></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
      <select name="state">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**PHP Error Array Dump:**

```
array(5) {
  ["first_name"]=>
  string(30) "First Name is a required field"
  ["last_name"]=>
  string(29) "Last Name is a required field"
  ["phone"]=>
  string(25) "Phone is a required field"
  ["email"]=>
  string(25) "Email is a required field"
  ["state"]=>
  string(21) "Please select a state"
}
```

Comment: @DevangRathod how can fiddle run `php code`??

Comment: @DipeshParmar you can run php code at http://phpfiddle.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
 <?php

    foreach($errorArray as $key=>$value)
    {
        $class = "$key_error";
        $$class = "class=error";
    }

?>

<table>
<tr>
<td align="right"><label for="first_name" <?php echo $first_name_error?>>First Name</label>      </td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" <?php echo $first_name_error?> name="first_name" id="first_name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><label <?php echo $last_name_error?> for="last_name">Last name</label></td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" <?php echo $last_name_error?> name="last_name" id="last_name"></td>
</tr>
   -------------
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How can I set it to something different than $first_name, $last_name, etc.? I need those to echo the values in the fields if errors are returned so the user doesn't have to re-fill everything out. Something like $first_name_error would be nice.